# Split(), usando | (pipe) como separador, não separa corretamente o texto

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app para android e fiz agora a parte de *HttpURLConnection*, coloquei tudo certo, apontei a *url* e fiz um teste com `System.out.printl(line)` e no console imprime a minha string com todos os dados que partem do meu arquivo php hospedado.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends  AsyncTask
{
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params)
    {
        HttpURLConnection conection;
        try
        {
            //Configuração de conexao
            URL url = new URL("http://prinxel.esy.es/horoscopo.php");
            conection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // Lendo os dados

            InputStream inputStream = conection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            //Storing data

            String line = new String();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println(line); // imprime todos os dados certinhos
                textoSeparado = line.split("|"); 
            }

            //Close Conection
            inputStream.close();
            conection.disconnect();

        }

        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return  null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
    }
}
```

Porém, quando uso o *split* para separar os item da minha string, não aparece nada no meu console.
Quero dividir para colocar em cada **text view** uma mensagem do meu *array* que será formado após o *split* da variável `line`.

Conteúdo da variável `line`

```
|Gêmeos vai sentir-se com algumas limitações que serão criadas apenas pela sua cabeça já que é um mês em que terá progresso e evolução.|Câncer estará bastante empenhado e concentrado no seu trabalho podendo esquecer-se por vezes da sua vida afetiva.|Leão terá um mês positivo em que poderá obter a realização que deseja em vários setores da sua vida.|
```

ps: Já tentei fazer `line.split("|")` fora do *while* e não funcionou

Comment: Quantas linhas são lidas?

Comment: Apenas uma, a line contém todos os meus dados. Quando eu separo utilizando split eu teria um array de 11 elementos, 0,1,2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[split()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) recebe como parâmetro um [regex](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular), como `|` tem uma função especial(é um meta-caractere) em *regex* ele não está a ser considerado como caractere separador.

Para garantir que o `|` é devidamente interpretado necessita de ser "escapado":

```
textoSeparado = line.split("\\|");
```

Outra forma de tratar meta-caracteres é usar [Pattern.quote()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

```
textoSeparado = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, entendi como funciona e resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Muito bom +1. =D